# Add Variables to Pipelines using the Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am currently using the pipeline REST endpoint documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) to create my pipelines and associate them with a YAML file, but there is no setting for adding variables in the docs.

For reference the setting I am looking for is the one you add here in the portal UI:

[image]

I'm not looking to set up variable groups which can be done using distributed  task endpoint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP) nor am I looking to add them to pipeline runs or build definitions which also have endpoints available documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2).

I just want to add them to the pipeline itself so that triggers tied to branch check-ins or manual runs have them available.

Unless I am not using them properly none of these endpoints mentioned are able to do the trick for me and I don't see any other options in the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Rest API: [Pipelines - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) to create the YAML Pipeline and set the Variable in Pipeline UI, you can refer to the following Request Body:

**Rest API:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=7.2-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

You can define the Pipeline variables in **configuration** field.

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "variables": {
            "variable1": {
                "value": "test1"
            },
            "variable2": {
                "value": "test2"
            }
        },
        "path": "azure-pipelines.yml",
        "repository": {
            "id": "{RepoID}",
            "type": "azureReposGit"
        },
        "type": "yaml"
    },
    "name": "{PipelineName}",
    "folder": "\\"
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That did the trick! I wish the docs included this option but I guess I could have tried it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do think `Run Pipeline` rest api helps ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)). `$RunPipelineVariables` is acting the same as the variables you pass when run the pipeline in UI.

below code I have used for a long time. It works well.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$OrganizationName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$ProjectName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$PipelineId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$BranchName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [hashtable]$RunPipelineVariables,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [hashtable]$Headers
)
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/pipelines/{2}/runs?api-version=7.0" -f $organizationName, $ProjectName, $PipelineId

$body = @{
    resources = @{
        repositories = @{
            self = @{
                refName = "refs/heads/" + $BranchName
            }
        }
    }
    variables = $RunPipelineVariables
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method 'Post' -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

a simple code to get header help you to test.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$UserName,
    [string]$PersonalAccessToken
)

$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f $UserName, $PersonalAccessToken)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth) }
return $headers
```